# Adding installed elasticsearch service into Ambari Web UI

Tags: elasticsearch, ambari

I am using HDP2.1、Ambari1.5.1 and I intend to add elasticsearch service into Ambari web ui, which can control the start&stop of elasticsearch.How can i do this?

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is not a service offered in the default HDP 2.1 stack. So you would need to create a custom service and add it to the HDP 2.1 stack. You can find out more about creating custom services on the [Ambari Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38571133).

Comment: Thanks for the reply！I followed this tutorial，however,the **add service** button in ambari web is disabled. So I can't add the elasticsearch service into the stack and control elasticsearch through ambari web.

The doc says the ambari version is too low.

Comment: Custom services can be added to Ambari 1.5.1 according to the documentation I linked. Since 1.5.1 is later then 1.5.0. What exactly said the ambari version is too low?