# How to add existing( already installed) service(Elasticsearch cluster) into Ambari

Tags: elasticsearch, ambari

I have a Elasticsearch cluster which is already installed and running.

Now I want to add Elasticsearch as a service in Ambari so that I can manage Elasticsearch's action(for example,start or stop) through Ambari Web UI.

How can I do this? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding installed elasticsearch service into Ambari Web UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415521/adding-installed-elasticsearch-service-into-ambari-web-ui)

Comment: You've already asked this question and received an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415521/adding-installed-elasticsearch-service-into-ambari-web-ui.

Comment: First thank you for answering again. Indeed , I've asked this question already. But this time ,I use HDP2.4 . The answer you gave me  can't solve my problem because my Elasticsearch is already installed.

Comment: In relation to your question there is no difference with the stack you were using before and the stack you are using now. HDP has never included elastic search as part of their ambari stack. A custom service has to be written if you want to manage it in ambari.

Answer (score 0):

Ambari cannot manage services that it did not provision.

HDP 2.4 does not include Elasticsearch as part of its stack. If you want to manage/monitor Elasticsearch you will have to create a custom service for the ambari stack. Details on creating a custom stack can be found on the [Ambari Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38571133)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have installed Elasticsearch( through a tar.gz way , not yum ), then how do I define <pacage> properties in metainfo.xml？

Comment: As I know, in HDP 2.4, Ambari use yum to install the package. Let me know if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: ElasticSearch provides an rpm package. You should use it instead of the tar.gz.

Comment: The problem is our Elasticsearch cluster（installed in tar.gz） is already running in production providing service. Is there a way to deal with it ?